# Debugging python module with VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a python program that takes a module as argument ( see `args`). The `launch.json` config is below:

```
{
        "name": "Python: Actions",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "my_module",
        "args": [
            "--module",
            "module"
        ],
        "cwd": "/cwd",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

When I run the program like this it works:
python -m my_module --module module

However, when I launch the debug config, it can't find the `module` passed as argument. Here is command line statement issued by vscode when I launch de config:

```
cd /cwd ; env "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /path/to/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.12.1/pythonFiles/ptvsd_launcher.py --default --client --host localhost --port 60664 -m my_module --module module
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_program remove cwd and add path to script maybe ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, VSCode's CLI parser needs a little help to avoid confusing its arguments with the module's:

```
{
        "name": "debugging-my-module",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "my_module",
        "args": [
            "--"
            "optional", 
            "args",
            "for",
            "your",
            "module",
        ],
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
},
```

Comment: Is your suggestion to remove the `cwd` option?

Comment: No, it is fine. Do add an extra "--" argument, that is what does the trick here.